# Iron Python script to capture Spotfire columns that have been marked and/or filtered and send them to a JSON?

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

I am currently working with this script:

```
import clr
import sys
clr.AddReference('System.Web.Extensions')
from System.Web.Script.Serialization import JavaScriptSerializer
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import IndexSet
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataValueCursor
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import*
import json



rowCount = Table.RowCount
rows = IndexSet(rowCount, True)
cols = Table.Columns
TableData = []

cursor = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(Table.Columns["cmf_value"])
markings = Document.Data.Markings["Inferenza"]

for r in rows:
    if markings.SetSelection(r,Table):
        item = {}
        for c in cols:
            item[c.Name] = c.RowValues.GetFormattedValue(r)
            if c.Name == 'model_type':
                item['model_type'] = c.RowValues.GetFormattedValue(r)
            if c.Name == 'cmf_value':
                item['cmf_value'] = c.RowValues.GetFormattedValue(r)
        TableData.append(item)

json_data = json.dumps(TableData, sort_keys = True, indent=4)
print(json_data)
```

That effectively does work in rendering me a JSON output. The problem is that I need to sure that the columns have filters and markings applied to them, and not just all of them regardless. How can I make sure that I am only taking the columns and rows I need?

Comment: You can filter and mark rows, but you cannot filter or mark individual columns (unless you do so from a second, different input table, where there is a variable containing the column names). So you need to somehow input the required columns into the script. One way of doing it would be to set up a multiple select list-box in a text area, where you can select the columns you want into a document property, which is then passed into, and used by, the script